# Implementing a event based State Machine in python tkinter

Tags: python, class, button, tkinter, state-machine

Say I have a derived button and a class State_Machine. This state machine has a variable called state. An event of button click should drive the initial state from 0 to 1, then 2, then 3 and then to 1 and so on. How do I go about implementing this?

```
import tkinter as tk

class myButtonClass(tk.Button):
...
...
self["command"]=self.Click

def Click()
   MySM = StateMachine()
   MySM.update_state()

class StateMachine:
...
...
def update_state():
...
...
print(self.state)
```

Please comment if the above seems to be a right choice of coding? or there is some other better way to do so without changing the classes and their variables being there. I want to maintain those classes.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your template code a new `StateMachine` will be created each time button is clicked.
You need to have a perstitent `StateMachine` object between calls to `Click()`

A simple but ugly way to achieve this would be to use a global variable:

```
# one time init outside of the event callback
MySM = StateMachine()

def Click()
   global MySM # retrieve the global state machine object
   MySM.update_state() # change its state
```